# Difference between plugins and presets in .babelrc

Tags: configuration, babeljs, rc

### Situation

So I have a `.babelrc` like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "es2015",
        "stage-2",
        "react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
}
```

### Question

What is the difference between presets and plugins? Which one should I use to configure Babel?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

### tl;dr

Presets are just a collection of plugins. You can include plugins individually in the `plugins` array, or collection of plugins in the `presets` array. If a plugin is part of a collection (preset), you don't have to include it individually in `plugins`.

The same goes for npm packages when you include them in `package.json`.

### Presets vs Plugins

Babel has lots of [official and third party plugins](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/). Presets are collections of plugins or [as they say](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets):

> Presets are sharable `.babelrc` configs or simply an array of babel plugins.

An important difference between the two is that [plugins are loaded before presets](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/plugins/#plugin-ordering).

### Plugins of a preset

The most common presets are the [official ones](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/#presets-official-presets) and the [discontinued experimental presets](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets).

Most of the official presets contain plugins to transpile features of the EcmaScript standards, while the experimental (stage-x) presets contained plugins that transpiled future experimental features whose standardization is still a work in progress. These experimental/proposal presets are deprecated since Babel 7. They have a [blog entry on the reasons](https://babeljs.io/blog/2018/07/27/removing-babels-stage-presets). Read the section below to see how they worked.

When you click on a preset, you can see which plugins (and maybe other presets) are included in it. If you include a plugin via a preset you don't have to include it individually. The same goes for `package.json` when you include the npm packages of the presets.

#### Deprecated proposal preset system

Going from stage 0 (just an idea) to stage 3 (candidate) you had collections of plugins that were more closer to getting standardized. Because of this, when you included a preset, every preset with a higher stage-x value were included too. The plugins contained in these presets were continuously varying in each version, since they are a work in progress, and there is a chance that plugins will be removed if they got rejected. That is why you needed [transform-decorators-legacy](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) because, decorator transpiling was earlier removed from Babel, although [they added it back later](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-decorators/).